# EOS-1v not compatible with non EF, manual lenses?

Tags: canon, manual-mode, 35mm, canon-1v

Wondering if I'm lucky enough to bump into an EOS-1v owner here, I'm having problem with non EF lenses on this camera.

The question: does 1v work with non-Canon lenses (converted to EF mount) at all?

I have two manual lenses with EF converters, and the camera simply does not take pictures with any of those. Every time as soon as I press shutter, the mirror lifts up as usual, but the empty battery icon blinks (while all other displays go off) exactly as if the battery were dead, but it was full. After a few seconds everything goes back to normal, display comes back up, mirror returns and all that, except it doesn't roll in the next frame. So I'm assuming it's not taking pictures.

Things I've tried:

- I have a 5D Mark III and it has no problem with those lenses.
- The 1v shoots fine with EF lens or even no lens mounted,.
- The EF mount converters were properly coated and insulated so neither were messing with the electronic pins.
- I've gone through the user manual and all the custom functions, nothing was relevant (I know some cameras that don't work with these manual lenses by default).
- Battery is good, film roll is good, camera is brand new.
- And yes, I was operating on manual mode.

The only thing I can think of is just 1v does not operate with non EF lenses, even if this sounds ridiculous.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: I've got an EOS-1v HS, which is the EOS-1v with the PB-E2 Power Drive booster attachment and I've never had any problems using non EF lenses myself. Just to get some background information - are you using passive converters (no electrical interface) or is it an AF confirm adapter or anything like that? Have you used the same exact lens-adapter setup with the 5Dmk3 and got it working?

Comment: Also what shutter speeds are you working with? Do the shutter fire when the mirror flips up? Sometimes if the battery level is low (even though you have good voltage there could be a problem with the camera detecting this) the mirror will flip and the shutter will fire and not return until you half press the trigger again. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Hugo, answer your questions: - yes the converters are all non electrical, and they all work on the 5d3 with the very same setup. Shutter speeds were around 1/15. I just tried a few more time with only converter mounted so I could see the shutter - no the curtain does not open when mirror goes up. And I doubt it's the battery, I got half a dozen of new batteries and the result is always the same

Comment: Very strange indeed. I really don't know what the problem is but I will try to replicate them later this week using some other converters.

Comment: Hey Hugo, thanks for the help! I think I found the problem, please see my answer down. I honestly did not know EF mount has this random mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

After some digging, I *think* the problem was caused by both adapters tripping a small switch inside the lens socket. Here (this is not EOS 1v body):[image]

I found [this article](http://photonotes.org/articles/eos-manual-lenses/) describing the issue (it's quite long, search for "Camera locks up with the manual focus lens installed"). Basically, once the switch is engaged, the camera will expect an electronic lens. According to the author, the camera locks up when it fails to communicate with the lens. However I have yet to find any good source on this. 5DIII works with these adapters because it does not have this switch.

The author's workaround seems to work - although dangerous - leave the lens unlocked and turn it back towards release a little, so the adapter does not trip that switch.

Comment: Oh, I guess the adapter I have does not engage that switch then. Sorry that I couldn't help but great that you seem to have found the problem.

Comment: Diamond files are an adapter users best friend. However, metal filings are his worst enemy, so clean thoroughly.